# Modify a smartdiagram

Tags: diagrams

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame}
\smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]{
  {Enseignement,{Large spectre de modules. Documents pédagogiques. Utilisation des outils en ligne de l’université. }},
  {Charges collectives, {Participation à
l’ensemble des manifestations}},
  {Recherche, {Savoir faire modélisation. Complémentarité avec les compétences de l’équipe}},
  {Pluridisciplinarité, {Mécanique, physique, mathématiques appliquées}}}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can I change the radius of the cycles or modify them to ellipses if necessary? Also how can I modify the height and the length of the rectangles?

Comment: Regarding the width of the rectangels: `\smartdiagramset{description text width=8cm}` or any other length of your choice. For more options seepage 9 of the smartdiagram documentation.

Answer (score 1):

[leandris already told you how to change the width of the rectangles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483866/modify-a-smartdiagram#comment1223411_483866). Here is how you can make the circles become ellipses.

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{description title/.append style={ellipse, text width=2cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame}
\smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]{
  {Enseignement,{Large spectre de modules. Documents pédagogiques. Utilisation des outils en ligne de l’université. }},
  {Charges collectives, {Participation à
l’ensemble des manifestations}},
  {Recherche, {Savoir faire modélisation. Complémentarité avec les compétences de l’équipe}},
  {Pluridisciplinarité, {Mécanique, physique, mathématiques appliquées}}}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]